# Disable Android from emitting LogCat messages

Tags: android, logcat

Is it possible to disable Android on a device from emitting ALL log messages from ALL apps?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: To see if too much data being sent from it is causing my PC to crash.

Comment: You can set a "tag" to filter at the top. So, I guess you could set something like "show me nothing" then you will not see anything in logcat, but the messages are still sent, just filtered out of the display.

Comment: No, I want to prevent messages from being sent.

Answer (score 1):

On a rooted device maybe. With your own ROM mod, certainly. Otherwise, no. Bear in mind the logs are kept even when your tools are not looking at those logs (e.g., device is disconnected from your development machine).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. Some devices (like Huawey's) got logging disabled and you have to do some magic to get this functionality restored, but this is just custom firmware modification by huawey.

Answer (score 0):

On a Huawei device, you dial:

```
*#*#2846579#*#*
```

This will bring up an app where you can disable all log messages. I'm sure every device has some secret phone number that lets you do this. No rooting necessary.